# How to remove PInvoke.net Visual Studio 2013 Add-on

Tags: pinvoke, visual-studio-2013, add-on

How do I remove the PInvoke.Net menu option from VS 2013.  It does not show up in the add on manager or anywhere else that I can see.  It also is not in the extension folder.  Unless I have no looked in the right places.  It is no longer used.

Thanks

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Use Tools + Customize to remove dead menu items.

Comment: From the pinvoke.net website it has a link to the MSDN Visualstudiogallery section that lets you run the installer that installs the extension.  The installer only installs.  No option to uninstall.

Comment: Tools + Customize was it.  I deleted the item from the menu.  Not sure how clean that is considering it really is not really 'dead' or uninstalled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the main Visual Studio menu TOOLS - Extensions and Updates - Installed - All - PInvoke.net Visual Studio Extension, click Uninstall.

Comment: Yup, that does it.  Thanks.